# Nested inner join in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to Inner Join five tables using **Sequelize**. I know I have to use `required: true` for inner join. But even after using the `required: true` it is not generating the query I am trying to achieve. Here, I have attached the code without the `required: true` statement. How should I place the `required: true` statement to inner join the five tables?

```
const db = require('../models');

const data = await db.A.findAll({
    where: conditionA,
    include: [{
        model: db.B,
        where: conditionB,
        include: [
            {
                model: db.C,
                where: conditionC,
                include: [{
                    model: db.D,
                    where: conditionD
                }],
            },
            {
                model: db.E,
                where: conditionE,
            }
        ]
    }]
});
```

Model associations

```
db.A.hasMany(db.B);
db.C.hasMany(db.B);
db.E.hasMany(db.B);
db.D.hasMany(db.C);

db.B.belongsTo(db.A);
db.B.belongsTo(db.C);
db.B.belongsTo(db.E);
db.C.belongsTo(db.D);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show model associations

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: Did you try `subQuery: false` option indicated in `A`  options?

Comment: And yes, you should indicate `required: true` in all model's options in `include`'s

Comment: I haven't tried "subQuery: false". So I have edited the code as you said. Should I try this? Sorry for sharing the code here.

await db.A.findAll({
 where: conditionA,
 required: true,
 subQuery: false,
 include: [{
  model: db.B,
  where: conditionB,
  required: true,
  include: [
   {
    model: db.C,
    where: conditionC,
    required: true
    include: [{
     model: db.D,
     where: conditionD,
     required: true
    }],
   },
   {
    model: db.E,
    where: conditionE,
    required: true
   }
  ]
 }]
});

Comment: Yes, but `required: true` in main options makes no sense, remove it.

Comment: Thank you so much. "subQuery: false" part worked. You can post it as the answer. 
One last query. Why do I need "subQuery: false"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should indicate `required: true` for all models in `include` options and indicate `subQuery: false` to make Sequelize to use usual JOINs instead of JOINs with subqueries.